# Selenium script stopes after some time

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

I have a selenium script that runs fine but when I am executing the same script in loop it stops after some time (1 to 2 hours).

Following is the error:

```
INFO: ERROR in Record- session d5609515-432f-4b01-b93d-b3b5571e009d does not exist
```

Kindly help me.

Comment: what script? can you give an example?

Comment: The script is automation of business process of client side.

Comment: We need more than that, we need to see the script itself, mainly the part where it fails. and if possible the code of what it's testing against

Answer (score 0):

It's seems that in that process you have time that the page not changing and the session expires, for example in bank account's sites if there is no action on page it will kill your session after x seconds.

keep always focus on the website even if you processing other thing's

> Exception: ERROR in Record- session
>   d5609515-432f-4b01-b93d-b3b5571e009d does not exist

tells you that you trying to use driver for any propose with session identification that not exist expired, for what i know it's session timeout

one more important thing if you have to do your script for (1 to 2 hours) you need to think about ways to split it for better results, it's internet and it's not always stable.

> Session Has Expired error on the Internet
>
> ErrorWhen browsing a website that is database driven, requires a
>   login, or is secured, you may see a "Session Expired" or "Session Has
>   Expired" error. The causes of these error messages are detailed in the
>   following sections.
>
> ```
> Inactivity - If you have not been doing anything on the page for a set length of time (often 10-30min) the server will time out your
> ```
>
> session. This is often done for security reasons and to help increase
>   the overall speed of the web page. In other words if you were browsing
>   the page and get up and leave, go to lunch, or start browsing other
>   pages when you come back you need to re-login and create a new
>   session.
>       Date or time not correct - Make sure the date and time are properly set on your computer.
>       Cookies - If you are browsing anonymously or your browser does not have cookies enabled it causes many sessions to fail. Make sure your
>   Internet cookies are enabled.
>       Firewall or proxy - If you are connecting to the Internet behind a firewall or through a proxy the firewall or proxy may be restricting
>   or prohibiting the session from being established.
>       Other site related issue - If this issue is only occurring on a certain site and you're not encountering any of the above-related
>   issues it's possible that it could be the site encountering an issue.
>   Contact the company or Webmaster to verify the problem is not on their
>   end.

Comment: I am not sure the problem in script or client application. How do i know the root cause of the same. If the problem is from client application haw can i get log for same.

Comment: you can try to trace that event and see where exactly it's throwing the exception but i think it will be randomly

Comment: Yes it is random, not coming on same place. The script takes only 2 to 3 minutes but that runs 500 to 1000 times. Is there any way to restart the partial process again whenever stuck.Or any workaround to achieve the flow.

Comment: yes catch the exception look if its session one and if it's is login to the site again

Comment: Is there way to check the problem is of code side or application side?

Comment: server side will defined the user session timeout.